# Is using QueryHistory from powershell to query windows updates on remote machine possible

Tags: windows, powershell, updates

**before someone is thinking, hey this question is easy to answer (=> yes...)
please keep on reading...**

i know, we can get an instance of `"Microsoft.Update.Session`" from a remote machine with (for example) the following code

```
[activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$ComputerName))
```

and this works for other actions like search for Updates that are installed `IsInstalled = 0`.

To get a full list of all updates (also pending etc.) there are a **lot** of examples on the internet, even here on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

they all write to do the following

```
$Session = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$ComputerName))
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$TotalUpdatesCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$TotalUpdates = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $TotalUpdatesCount)
```

*And it seems that it is working because there is no error.... and we have a nice (big) list of Updates...*

My problem is, the Result of `QueryHistory(int, int)` returns is always the same... no matter what `$ComputerName` i have entered at the `CreateInstance(...GetTypeFromProgID(..., $ComputerName))` part

And **no one** on all the sites who are giving examples is mentioning this, i believe they all used the code `locally` because in that scope it is returning the correct values...

after investigating deeper and reading the **MSDN** i found the following *statement* on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394842(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Note that QueryHistory supports per-machine updates only.
```

---

To sum um,

**my Question is**: Is it Possible to use QueryHistory in Powershell to get a list of Updates on a remote machine `(without invoke... that requires PSRemoting... / or tools like psexec...)` and if yes, how?

Comment: You want to remotely run PowerShell code without using PSRemoting? That's like asking how to knock in a nail without using a hammer... there are options but they are going to be ugly solutions if you don't want to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do the exact same thing. But everywhere, Invoke-command seems to be the go to method. [Been working on a tool called Windows Patching Assistant (https://powershellchronicles.com/portfolio/windows-patching-assistant/) that direly needs a method better than that.]. It is not always feasible or allowed (for perhaps security reasons) to configure WinRM (Required for PSremoting) wherever you want.

Comment: i think the problem is, `QueryHistory` does not use the additional Parameter given at `CreateInstance(...GetTypeFromProgID(..., $ComputerName))` and thats why the method `QueryHistory` always returns values for the local computer this runs on...

Of course other methods like `CreateUpdateSearcher().Search("IsInstalled=0")` does indeed **work**... (without psremoting...)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I still can't figure it out, but the last approach I came up with is:

1. Write a ps1 script with the code needed to run QueryHistory
2. write another ps1 script that creates a process on the remote machine using

   ```
   Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $cmd_command_string -Computername $computerName -erroraction Stop -Credential $credential
   ```
3. this is `$cmd_command_string`: it basically opens a cmd that fires a powershell

   ```
   $cmd_command_string="cmd /C powershell.exe -EncodedCommand " + $ps_command_stringEncoded + " >> C:\Windows\output.log"
   ```
4. now write the code that reads the first ps1 you've written, puts it in a string and encodes it in base64 (that's what is `$ps_command_stringEncoded` in the code block above)
5. wait the process to end, then retrieve the output file.

Seems legit to me, but someway I can't make it work. If somebody wants to give it a try...

**EDIT**: I ended up copying a VBS script on the remote machine, calling QueryHistory from that script, writing output on file, retrieving that remote file back. Dirty, but it works.